# A vocalist musician beginner: hearing song structure

Tags: analysis, ear-training, songwriting, musical-forms

How to tell the parts of a song  when I hear a beat?
I mean if I find a beat that I love, how can I tell in which seconds the chorus, verses,bridge...?

For example, what distinguishes the different parts of "[Stuck in Your Dreams](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SWT--W3OsSE&list=PLVNjC8_Dg6XDJECanYtx6oDRIM7HRBZ0K&index=2&t=0s)" by The Weeknd?

Answer (score 2):

To my ear, it's not just the beats that distinguish the parts of the song. I hear it this way:

- 0:00 - 0:39: **Introduction**. The high sound that begins at 0:36 is the signal that something is about to change.
- 0:39 - 1:05: **Verse 1**. Now we're in a consistent groove, and the vocal is more well-defined. Another high sound, beginning at 1:02, I interpret as a signal for a new part.
- 1:05 - 1:32: **Verse 2**. Really just a repeat of verse 1, with the difference that the beat empties out for the first half before returning for the second half.
- 1:32 - 2:11: **Interlude**. Doesn't sound to me like a chorus -- which typically serves in contrast the verses -- or a bridge -- which typically serves to link the verses. It sounds more like the music is taking a short break. Note that the high sound returns again at 2:08 to signal the next section.
- 2:11 - 2:38: **Verse 3**.
- 2:38 - 3:20: **Ending**. The texture empties out just as in verse 2, but unlike verse 2, they don't return in the same way. They come in later, and in the more ambiguous form heard in the introduction.
- 3:20 - 3:25: **Coda**. The final "hollow" sound is tacked onto the end to help bring everything to a gentle close.

A couple of additional points of interest:

- The verses are each the same length. This is in part how we can interpret verse 1 and verse 2 as being separate -- by their being the same length as verse 3.
- The introduction, interlude, and ending are also the same length, with the slight exception that the ending is extended by three seconds for a fade-out.
- This piece follows a very standard [song form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Song_structure): [AABA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Song_structure#AABA_form) (i.e., verse, verse, interlude, verse)., with the inclusion of an introduction and ending/coda.